# Android Studio 3.4 build fails with openJDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.4

OS: Debian Stretch

Android Studio 3.4

JDK: open jdk 1.8

My Android studio build fails with following error:

> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK
>   (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to
>   point to the according directory.

I set JAVA_HOME, STUDIO_JDK etc and tried various tricks with openjdk , with no luck.

My default JRE is set to default as recommended [image]

I am trying to update default JDK location as follow which given another error:
[image]

Already killed couple of hours to resolve this issue. So give android studio 3.4, my questions are:

1. What is wrong with the built-in compiler ?
2. Is openJDK 1.8 is valid jdk for android studio 3.4 to build/compile projects ? Or do I need Oracle-jdk?
3. I see oracle-jdk licensing has changed, can I use that for building commercial apps ?

**Edit**
  I found later that the issue was , debian stretch installed jvm only. I tried to run `javac -version` which fails since by default stretch got jre only. Later I fixed by installing openjdk-8-jdk which fixed the issue:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

`javac -version`

> javac 1.8.0_212

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and while i parsing google i found an interesting site.
In a lot of water i read the main information(in my opinion):

> Android Studio requires Oracle Java 1.6 or later. It won’t work with OpenJDK.

I think we need to download oracle, becuase i see you are using java v 1.8 like me.
I didn't try that, but i think it will work.

Comment: You cannot officially download oracle jdk anymore :(